# jQuery div children with specific class

Tags: jquery, css, children

Let's say I have following div:

```
<div id="main">
     <div class="a">...</div>
     <div class="a">...</div>
     <div class="b">...</div>
     <div class="b">...</div>
</div>
```

I need to get count of main div's children with speciic class. Without second condition I would do this like that and it works:

```
$('#main').children().length
```

How to get only divs with class "a" ? Result should be 2, not 4.

Comment: just pass in `'.a'` as a parameter to `.children()`, RTFM => http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
$('#main .a').length;
```

or

```
$('.a','#main').length; //which is equivalent to $('#main').find('.a').length
```

Answer (score 1):

**[WOrking Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pZLU/)**

Give a try to this

```
 $('#main div.a').length;
```

A/C @PlantTheIdea Comment:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/pkLdc/3/)**

```
$('#main').children('.a').length;
```